# Reference request: dark matter and $f(R)$ modified gravity

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, resource-recommendations, dark-matter, modified-gravity

Could someone please explain briefly or refer me to an article or manuscript that shows how $f(R)$ modified gravity theories can be used to explain the problem of dark matter, particularly the galaxy rotation problem?

Comment: [Wikipedia overview on modified Newtonian dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOND)

Comment: I already checked that out, could you suggest more.

Comment: The Wikipedia article lists thirty references. Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: Have you tried [ADS](http://adswww.harvard.edu/)? Or Google Scholar? Or any search engine?

Answer (score 2):

I quite enjoyed [this article](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015CaJPh..93..250M) that contrasts the standard $\Lambda{\rm CDM}$ cosmology and $\rm MOND$ (for other flavours of modified gravity, you'd have to look elsewhere). The author does a pretty good job of stating the cases for and against both theories. Figure 4 may be of particular interest. It's not very technical, so if you want a derivation of the predictions of $\rm MOND$ you won't find it here, but it is well referenced, so it might point you somewhere interesting.